# Error in assign a numeric value

Tags: r

I would like to transform a string into a number. This is my code:

```
test <- starwars
home <- test$homeworld
home <- as.numeric(home)
```

but I have this error:

```
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

My goal is to assign a number to every `homeworld`. Obviously the lines with the same `homeworld` will have the same number assigned.

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read it, you want to transform `home` to contain numbers instead of text, with similar numbers representing similar homeworlds.

As r correctly states, you cannot turn a list into a single numeric (double) value. Instead, you first have to convert the list into a factor.

To do this in R, you run:

```
data(starwars, package = "dplyr")
df <- starwars
home <- df$homeworld
home_numeric <- as.numeric(as.factor(home))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: With this example works, but with my real dataset I have a list of NA value and I don't understand why..

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your real dataset, as otherwise it is impossible to provide a fitting answer to your question.

Comment: Ok, now it works! Thank you!